# Can I access the ViewData from the HttpContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, viewdata, controllercontext

Im working with a project that sets variables such as the current user profile object in its authorize action filter, storing them in the `ViewData` for access by the following action method.

The action method then calls functionality from the repository. I'm trying to find a way to access the `ViewData` from the repository **WITHOUT modifying the repository's method signature**, and am hoping there is a way I can track back to it via the `HttpContext.Current` functionality which I can call from the repository.

Can anyone help with this? Just to be clear, the only code that I can modify is within the repository method :(

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    [MyAuthorize]                   // ViewData items are set here
    public void MyAction(int id)
    {
        new MyRepository().DoSomething(id); // Need to access ViewData items within this repository method and am unable to alter the method signature :(
    }
}
```

Comment: So this is in a filter before it gets to the repo?

Comment: Correct, I will post a code example. Thanks

Comment: The only way you could do this is by registering the ViewData into an IoC or something and resolve it from inside the repo... That doesn't sound v clean though IIH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is "no".

When you review the ASP.NET MVC source code, [`ControllerBase`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerBase.cs) instantiates a ViewData dictionary on first use. Then when you call `View()`, a new `ViewResult` is instantiated with the `ControllerBase.ViewData` dictionary as a parameter. It does not look like it gets applied to a public static property or class like `HttpContext` which you could access from inside your repository.

I think your best bet would be to use [`HttpContext.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.items.aspx) which is built for this type of communication. Though probably not as ideal as just modifying the repository to accept the extra data.

Comment: If you get the viewdata inside a filter and put it somewhere static you acn grab it later but yeah - messy